# Burninate [loading], or split it?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, burninate-request

[loading](/questions/tagged/loading) seems too generic. I just rejected a tag wiki edit [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/875856) for that tag; however, the edit was eventually approved by 3 votes against 2.

I saw that tag being used in at least the following contexts:

- Issues when loading content/resources from disk or server into an application or web page
- Loading indicators (like ajax activity indicators, progress bars and splash screens)
- `load` events (such as JS `window.onload`, or Windows Forms `Form_Load`
- Preloaders (as in HTML/JS image preloading techniques)
- Assorted uses like [reloading a config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167705/not-restarting-emacs), [loading a program module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769534/dynamic-loading-of-python-modules), [reading data from a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046610/mysql-best-method-to-saving-and-loading-items), etc.

Although all those cases might be considered "loading", IMO they're not similar enough to use the same tag. So maybe the tag should be split into several more specific tags.

Comment: When you check the definition in that tag wiki, and do a quick eyeball of the questions tagged with it then it appears to have been used reasonably legitimately. With 1100+ questions tagged with it I personally would be reluctant to agree to a burnination - it appears to be commonly paired with a web based technology (jQuery, HTML, etc).

Comment: The fact that it has a tag wiki doesn't mean it's not an *awful* tag.  It can not reasonably stand alone on a question, and the definition of it changes based the other tags.

Comment: @slugster I think it's used on fairly different contexts, see my edits above. On a side note, the tag wiki is currently not showing, although the suggested edit was approved, and appears as the [last revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11601969/revisions). I'm not sure why.